# Open specific trail with a url scheme from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, json, url, nsdictionary

I am using TouchJSON to retrieve the JSON response from http://enbr.co.cc/TrailsApp/shops.php. In my app I use this code to handle a url scheme.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if (!url) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    NSString *urlStringDecoded = [urlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSArray *list = [urlStringDecoded componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *urlPrefix = [list objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *name = [list objectAtIndex:1];
    if ([urlPrefix isEqualToString:@"tridetrails://opentrail?name"]) {
        TrailViewController *trailViewController = [[TrailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TrailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        trailViewController.trailToGoto = name;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:trailViewController animated:YES];
        [trailViewController release];
    }
    if ([urlPrefix isEqualToString:@"tridetrails://openshop?name"]) {
        ShopViewController *shopViewController = [[ShopViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShopViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        shopViewController.shopToGoto = name;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:shopViewController animated:YES];
        [shopViewController release];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

How can I push the correct entry from my NSDictionary created from the JSON to the ShopViewController based on the NSString name? Here is my dictionary printed out by NSLog with NSLog(@"%@", myObj);. Thanks in advance.

```
{
    shops =     (
                {
            blurb = "Bootdoctors blurb";
            image = bootdoctorslogo;
            locations = "Mountain Village";
            motto = "Bootdoctors shop motto";
            name = Bootdoctors;
        },
                {
            blurb = "Easy Rider blurb";
            image = easyriderlogo;
            locations = Telluride;
            motto = "Easy Rider shop motto";
            name = "Easy Rider";
        },
                {
            blurb = "Paragon Ski & Sport blurb";
            image = paragonskiandsportlogo;
            locations = Telluride;
            motto = "Paragon shop motto";
            name = "Paragon Ski & Sport";
        },
                {
            blurb = "Telluride Sports blurb";
            image = telluridesportslogo;
            locations = "Telluride and Mountain Village";
            motto = "Telluride Sports shop motto";
            name = "Telluride Sports";
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to give a bit more information about what you are trying to do. For instance you don't say how you retrieve the dictionary containing the details of all the shops and how ShopViewController has access to this dictionary. But selecting one shop by name from the dictionary can be done with something like this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonResponse; // You don't say how the ShopViewController has access to
                            // the response so let's just assume a local variable here.

NSDictionary *foundShop = nil; // This will be selected shop after the search below

NSArray *shops = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@'shops'];

for (NSDictionary *shop in shops) {
    if ([shop objectForKey:@'name'] isEqualToString:self.shopToGoto]) {
        foundShop = shop;
        break;
    }
}

if (foundShop) {
    // Do something with the dictionary keys and values in foundShop
}
else {
    // Error condition - shop with required name is not present
    // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a NSPredicate to select the shop(s) you are looking for:

```
    NSString* shopName = ...;

    NSArray* shops = ...;  // this is your JSON-produced array of NSDictionary Shop objects

    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name == '%@'", shopName ];

    NSArray* matchingShops = [shops filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];

    NSDictionary* firstMatchingShop = [matchingShops objectAtIndex: 0];
```